# write constructor to initialize attributes csharp?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

Hey Guys i could need some Help here.
I'm supposed to implement an abstract class with some attributes (that I already have). Now I'm supposed to write a constructor that initializes the attributes and add getters and setters. Here I am stuck can someone tell me how to implement this?

**Here is my abstract class**

```
namespace Personalverwaltung { 

    public abstract class Person
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Adresse;
        public int Hausnummer;
        public int PLZ;
        public string Ort;   
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you learn anything by someone just doing your homework for you?

Comment: Please be aware that the right word to use here is *fields*. I mention this because there is a concept in C# called *attributes*, and that's not what you're working with here.

Comment: im searching for a solution for like 3 hours now i just maybe some strong tips because im really new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no Getters and Setters in C# (at least they are not advised as in i.e. Java implementations), there are only properties.

Take a look here to help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Example:

```
   private double _seconds;

   public double Hours
   {
       get { return _seconds / 3600; }
       set {
          if (value < 0 || value > 24)
             throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                   $"{nameof(value)} must be between 0 and 24.");

          _seconds = value * 3600;
       }
   }
```

For an example constructor, look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Both articles will help you learn when you implement them. There are enough examples and information to get you going. Good luck on your programming journey.

Comment: Thnak you i hope this will help <3#